# react-redux app issue - trying to pass mapped array data from parent to child

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-toolkit

hi guys I am trying to create a react app using redux toolkit , it has add to cart functionality
when I try to pass props to parent component to child component I am getting below issue please check if you can

I am getting the below error in console

**the error message in console  -- 'add' is not defined**

### parent react component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectAddSlice } from "./features/auth/addsSlice";

import Cardshild from './Cardshild'
const Addtocart = (props) => {

 

  return (
    <div>
      {selectedAdds.map((add, i) => (
        <Cardshild key={i} allprops={add.allprops} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Addtocart;
```

### child react component

```
import React from 'react'

const Cardshild = ({id, addname, price, quantity}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            
            <div key={add.id}>
              <div> {add.addname}</div>
              <div> {add.price}</div>
             
              <button onClick={(e) =>{  e.preventDefault(); add.quantity++ }}>+</button>
              <div> {add.quantity}</div>
              <button onClick={(e) =>{  e.preventDefault(); add.quantity-- }}>-</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Cardshild
```

---

### below is json data and this data is in redcux also  what I am trying to do is when clicking the incriment or decrement button trying to update the quantity

[
{
"addname": "normaladd",
"price": "23",
"id": "1",
"quantity":0
},
{
"addname": "advancedadd",
"price": "50",
"id": "2",
"quantity":0
},
{
"addname": "premiumadd",
"price": "100",
"id": "3",
"quantity":0
}

]

Answer (score 1):

What issue?
You can't just show the code and ask I have an issue, fix it for me.

Next time you should be more specified if you need helps. 
I don't know the issue so I just correct the code:

 In the parent

```
{selectedAdds.map((add, i) => (
    <Cardshild key={i} allprops={add} />
  ))}
```

In the child

```
<div key={id}>
   <div> {addname}</div>
   <div> {price}</div>           
   <button onClick={(e) =>{  e.preventDefault(); quantity++ }}>+</button>
   <div> {quantity}</div>
   <button onClick={(e) =>{  e.preventDefault(); quantity-- }}>-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: im new here , next time ill update in a good way,  is it ok if I edit the question ?

Comment: Yes, sure. Describe your issue or post an image of the console window or anything that could help us understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get data from parent to child so previously and error message was showing.

***now I updated the code and it fixed the issue***

below is my react component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectAddSlice } from "./features/auth/addsSlice";

import Cardshild from './Cardshild'
const Addtocart = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      {selectedAdds.map((add, i) => (
        <Cardshild key={i} add={add} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Addtocart;
```

below is my child component

---

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const Cardshild = ({add}) => {

    const [amount, setamount] = useState(add.quantity)

    return (
        <div>
            
            <div key={add.id}>
              <div> {add.addname}</div>
              <div> {add.price}</div>
             
              <button onClick={(e) =>{  e.preventDefault(); setamount(amount + 1) }}>+</button>
              <div> {amount}</div>
              <button onClick={(e) =>{  e.preventDefault(); if(amount > 0){
                  setamount(amount - 1)
              }}}>-</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Cardshild
```